# Using refcursor as an input to an function in oracle, getting error - cannot access rows from a non-nested table item while executing

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I have a requirement in which I need to pass multiple/no values from a dropdown in a webpage to a sql function and based on the input value it should return output(again a refcursor).

Function code -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION KAG9802.GET_INJUREDPARTYTYPE
(name_in IN SYS_REFCURSOR)

   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS 
 my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
var1 varchar2(50);


BEGIN



LOOP
FETCH name_in INTO var1;

IF var1 = 'Near Miss' THEN

OPEN my_cursor
             for SELECT 1 from dual;
ELSE

 OPEN my_cursor
            for select 2 from dual;

   END IF ;
EXIT WHEN name_in%NOTFOUND;



end loop;

RETURN my_cursor;
close name_in;
END;
```

While executing the function like this:

```
select * FROM TABLE ( GET_INJUREDPARTYTYPE(
CURSOR
 (
    select 'abcd'  from dual
    union
    select 'efgh'  from dual) 
) );
```

I am getting the error

> ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item

Also I am not sure whether this is a good approach to test the input values from the dropdown. Please advise.

Comment: `table()` function must return a **nested table** object not a ref cursor (which is just a pointer). It's hard to understand what you're trying to do by reversing engineering business logic from toy code. So we can' really say whether this is a *"good approach"*. Although it does seem convoluted.I suggest you re-write your question to explain the logic you're trying to implement, with proper sample inout values and desired outcomes derived from those samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning a `CURSOR` you could return a `PIPELINED` collection:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_INJUREDPARTYTYPE(
  name_in IN SYS_REFCURSOR
) RETURN SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST PIPELINED
IS 
  my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
  name      VARCHAR2(50);
  int_value INTEGER;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    FETCH name_in INTO name;
    EXIT WHEN name_in%NOTFOUND;

    IF name = 'Near Miss' THEN
      OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT 1 FROM dual;
    ELSE
      OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT 2 FROM dual;
    END IF ;
    LOOP
      FETCH my_cursor INTO int_value;
      EXIT WHEN my_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      PIPE ROW ( int_value );
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE my_cursor;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE name_in;
END;
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(
         get_injuredPartyType(
           CURSOR(
             SELECT 'abc'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
             SELECT 'Near Miss' FROM DUAL
           )
         )
       );
```

Will output:

> ```
> | COLUMN_VALUE |
> | -----------: |
> |            2 |
> |            1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=135562793c2bf09c31ba4094fa6fa369)*

Comment: The requirement has changed and I have to return column values in the output -

OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT INJUREDPARTYTYPE_NAME FROM HSERS_INJUREDPARTYTYPE_DIM;
else 
OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT  INJUREDPARTYTYPE_NAME FROM HSERS_INJUREDPARTYTYPE_DIM  where INJUREDPARTYTYPE_NAME IN ('Sub','JV');

I have changed the int_value to be varchar2 type, still while executing the SELECT query to call function, 
I am getting error ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error. Please advise.

Comment: @Vasudevan Please ask a new question rather that trying to creep the scope of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is correct but you are calling it with the wrong syntax.

You need to create the cursor and pass it to the function and also, assign the return value to other function.

Something like the following:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUT ON
SQL>
SQL> DECLARE
  2      MY_CUR    SYS_REFCURSOR;
  3      MY_CUR1   SYS_REFCURSOR;
  4  BEGIN
  5      OPEN MY_CUR FOR SELECT
  6                          'abcd'
  7                      FROM
  8                          DUAL
  9                      UNION
 10                      SELECT
 11                          'efgh'
 12                      FROM
 13                          DUAL;
 14
 15      MY_CUR1 := GET_INJUREDPARTYTYPE(MY_CUR);
 16      DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(MY_CUR1);
 17  END;
 18  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

ResultSet #1

         2
----------
         2

SQL>
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you! 
but I am not able to use ddl statements in the query triggered for the dropdown value.